# Как одновременно отправить и данные из формы, и переменную?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Отправляю данные из формы:

```
function call() {
    var mineForm = $('#mineForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'hand.php',
        data: mineForm,
        success: function() {

        },
        error: function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
```

И есть переменная, назовем ее просто var, так вот, как отправить одним этим запросом данные из формы + var.

Comment: *Цитата: "есть переменная, назовем ее просто var"*. **var** в JavaScript, это зарезервированное слово. Оно не может использоваться в качестве имени переменной. Даже, если речь идёт о переменной условно, лучше избегать употребления зарезервированных слов, скажем так, в смысле отличном от их прямого назначения. Иначе это может привести к путанице.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю лучше всего добавить в форму

```
<input type="hidden" name="specvalue" id="specvalue" value="value"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно перед serialize сделать

```
$('#mineForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="name" value="val"/>');
```

либо

```
$('#mineForm').serialize() + '&name=val';
```